# Is it possible to create collections in MarkLogic similar to MongoDb

Tags: marklogic

I am new to this MarkLogic DB and till now we are using this for crud operations on XML documents using XQuery.

Now the requirement has changed a bit and need to store json data along with documents(could be xml/json) into different collections and perform crud operations using Java api + spring boot

The below 3 example collections hold json data similar to mongo db

```
Employee Collection  
-------------------
empid,
`emp id json`

Address Collecion
-----------------------
empid,
`address details json`

Documents collection
-----------------
empid , 
`document (xml/json  )`
```

Is this possible in MarkLogic DB ?. If yes, please help me in finding the way to this.

And need a search api to filter among the above 3 collections using Marklogic + Spring boot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  See: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/collections
(found by google for "MarkLogic Collections")

Comment: Keep in mind that MongoDB collections are more like directories in MarkLogic. A document can only be part of one collection in MongoDB, but can be part of many in MarkLogic. If you want each doc to be part of one 'collection' at a time, use directories in MarkLogic.